# Add additional View to the Index View in .Net 6

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-blob-storage, .net-6.0

I am pretty new in `.net 6` and I have to work on a larger project. In order to implement my code to the Project more effectively later on, I made a small project to test it out first.

I made the small application that takes Data from `Azure Blob Storage` and displays it on the screen with the following code:

**Controller**:

```
public class ResourceController : Controller
{
    const string blobContainerName = "blob_container_name";
    static BlobContainerClient? blobContainer;

    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ResourceController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        try
        {
            var s = _configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureConnectionString");

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(s);

            blobContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerName);
            await blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(PublicAccessType.Blob);

            List<Uri> allBlobs = new List<Uri>();
            foreach (BlobItem blob in blobContainer.GetBlobs())
            {
                if (blob.Properties.BlobType == BlobType.Block)
                    allBlobs.Add(blobContainer.GetBlobClient(blob.Name).Uri);
            }

            return View(allBlobs);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewData["message"] = ex.Message;
            ViewData["trace"] = ex.StackTrace;
            return View("Error");
        }
    }

}
```

**Model**:

```
public class ResourceViewModel
{
    public string? RequestId { get; set; }

    public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);
}
```

**View**:

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="imageBlock">
            <a href="@item" target="_blank"><img class="thumb" src="@item" alt="images"/></a><br />
            <div class="deleteDiv"><img class="deleteIcon" src="~/Images/deleteImage.png" title="Delete Image" onclick="deleteImage('@item');" /></div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Result (Don't mind the bad display, I just care about the functionality at the moment):

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyXs7.png)

**Because of the larger project that I have to fit in I created a new *Index* function with the new View, and renamed the previous *Index* to *GetGallery*, but I don't know How to implement the *GetGallery* to the Index function so it would show the images again.**

```
   public class ResourceController : Controller
    {
        const string blobContainerName = "blob_container_name";
        static BlobContainerClient? blobContainer;

        private IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ResourceController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
            // Add GetGallery Controller here
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> GetGallery()
        {
            try
            {
                var s = _configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureConnectionString");

                BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(s);

                blobContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerName);
                await blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(PublicAccessType.Blob);

                List<Uri> allBlobs = new List<Uri>();
                foreach (BlobItem blob in blobContainer.GetBlobs())
                {
                    if (blob.Properties.BlobType == BlobType.Block)
                        allBlobs.Add(blobContainer.GetBlobClient(blob.Name).Uri);
                }

                return View(allBlobs);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewData["message"] = ex.Message;
                ViewData["trace"] = ex.StackTrace;
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
}
```

**My Question is:** How could I rewrite my code so it displays the GetGallery function in the Index?
*P.S.:* If the question is not clear or need extra information please ask and I will try my best to give the extra information

Comment: You could check out view components - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Question is: How could I rewrite my code so it displays the
> GetGallery function in the Index?

To display the GetGallery view in the Index view, you can use the following methods:

1. Convert the GetGallery view as a partial view, then in the Index view, use the following code to render the GetGallery view:

   ```
    <partial name="/Views/Folder/_PartialName.cshtml" model="PartiaViewModel" />
    or
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName", PartiaViewModel)
   ```

   [Note]By using this method, in the Index action method, you have to get Data from Azure Blob Storage, then transfer it to the Index view page, then you can transfer the data to the partial view and display them.
2. Convert the GetGallery View as a partial view, then in the Index view, use JQuery Ajax to load the partial view.

   Here are some relate tutorials about using Partial View, if using the above methods, you can refer to them:

   [Partial views in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

   [Load Partial View using jQuery AJAX in ASP.Net Core MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-Partial-View-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet-Core-MVC.aspx)

   [Note]By using this method, in the controller, you need to change the GetGallery action method to return partial view.
3. Convert the GetGallery view as a View Components. You can refer to the following tutorials:

   [View components in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

   [ViewComponent In ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/viewcomponent-in-asp-net-core/)

We can use the above method to add one view in another view, but it you want to refresh the partial view, using the JQuery Ajax method is a good choice.